# NSDecimalNumber notANumber is not true for letter 'E'

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitextfield

Im trying to apply validation on `UITextField` in such a way that it should not accept anything rather than decimal number.
I used following `delegate` method of `UITextField`:

```
  - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{


     NSDecimalNumber *number2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:string];
    if (!string || [string length] < 1 || [string isEqualToString:@""] )
    {
        return YES;
    }
    if (!number2 || [number2 isEqualToNumber:[NSDecimalNumber notANumber]])
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Its working perfect,but it has two issues.

**1. when i'm entering value 'E' or 'e' its accepting it.**

**2.Once it accepted letter 'E' or 'e',Its accepting all other english letters.**

Comment: Can't you make UITextField keyboard as PhonePad?

Comment: `string` is the replacement text (log it) so your code is logically incorrect as it isn't verifying the text as it will be after the edit is allowed...

Comment: @user2071152 that application is for ipad,I cant use Phonepad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the documentation.

> Besides digits, numericString can
>   include an initial “+” or “–”; a single “E” or “e”, to indicate the
>   exponent of a number in scientific notation; and a single
>   NSLocaleDecimalSeparator to divide the fractional from the integral
>   part of the number.

Maybe you can use NSRegularExpression instead

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NSNumberFormatter` to validate numeric user input.